# Struggling to convert Pine Script from v1 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Please see below an indicator I found on Trading View. I want to convert it to v5 but there is no options appearing in tradingview pinescript. could anybody please help me to fix this?

Many thanks

```
study("Supertrend V1.0 - Buy or Sell Signal", overlay = true)

Factor=input(3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(7, minval=1,maxval = 100)


Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))


TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red

plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend")

plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The auto convert tool works starting from `v3`. So, you need to update it to `v3` yourself and then let the tool do its job.

The only thing you need to pay attention to is [self referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed).

```
//@version=5
indicator('Supertrend V1.0 - Buy or Sell Signal', overlay=true)

Factor = input.int(3, minval=1, maxval=100)
Pd = input.int(7, minval=1, maxval=100)

Up = hl2 - Factor * ta.atr(Pd)
Dn = hl2 + Factor * ta.atr(Pd)

TrendUp = 0.0
TrendUp := close[1] > TrendUp[1] ? math.max(Up, TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown = 0.0
TrendDown := close[1] < TrendDown[1] ? math.min(Dn, TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = 0.0
Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1 : close < TrendUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 1)
Tsl = Trend == 1 ? TrendUp : TrendDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red

plot(Tsl, color=linecolor, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title='SuperTrend')

plotshape(ta.cross(close, Tsl) and close > Tsl, 'Up Arrow', shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.new(color.green, 0), 0)
plotshape(ta.cross(Tsl, close) and close < Tsl, 'Down Arrow', shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.new(color.red, 0), 0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title='Up Entry Arrow', colorup=color.new(color.lime, 0), maxheight=60, minheight=50)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title='Down Entry Arrow', colordown=color.new(color.red, 0), maxheight=60, minheight=50)
```